# XPath - Attributes selection

Tags: objective-c, xpath, hpple

I have this code:

```
<p class='test'>
    Text1
</p>

<p class='test'>
    Text1
</p>
```

With Hpple (XPath), I need to read the first `<p class='test'>`, and the second, but I dont know how to do this.

Maybe like:

```
//p[@class='test'][1]
//p[@class='test'][2]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#import "TFHpple.h"

NSData  * data      = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"index.html"];
TFHpple * doc       = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];
NSArray * elements  = [doc search:@"//p[@class='test']"];

TFHppleElement * element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
[e content];              // Tag's innerHTML
[e tagName];              // "a"
[e attributes];           // NSDictionary of href, class, id, etc.
[e objectForKey:@"href"]; // Easy access to single attribute
```

You have more elements so loop the 'elements' array, in this case you could do [elements objectAtIndex:0] and [elements objectAtIndex:1].

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this tutorial: [XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) it wouuld be:

```
//p[@class='test']
```

Comment: Sorry, Laurens already solve this... Thanks for the attention! ;-)